# Linq2SQL storing XElement to SQL Server database removes whitespaces

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, whitespace, xelement

Can I force `System.Data.Linq.DataContext` to store XML into a SQL Server table's XML column preserving whitespace or is there any other way?

My test code is as follows:

```
        Guid MyNewQid = Guid.NewGuid();
        using (DataClassesDataContext context = DataClassesDataContext.CreateDataContext())
        {

            Guid myQID = Guid.Parse("{28da4eca-2c1a-4647-xxx-b398d1xxx013}");
            FromSwiftBck t2sData = context.GetTable<FromSwiftBck>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.QID == myQID);
            string messageLoaded = t2sData.CompleteMessage;
            int appHeaderLenght = messageLoaded.IndexOf("</AppHdr>") + 9;
            string strMsgHeader = messageLoaded.Substring(0, appHeaderLenght);
            string strMsgDocument = messageLoaded.Substring(appHeaderLenght);
            XElement serv = XElement.Parse(strMsgDocument, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);

            SwiftOut swOut = new SwiftOut();
            swOut.QID = MyNewQid;
            swOut.InsertTime = DateTime.Now;
            swOut.Message = serv;
            swOut.Status = -100;
            swOut.Namespace = swOut.Message.GetDefaultNamespace().NamespaceName;
            swOut.MessageName = swOut.Message.Descendants().First().Name.LocalName;

            context.SwiftOuts.InsertOnSubmit(swOut);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
        using (DataClassesDataContext context = DataClassesDataContext.CreateDataContext())
        { 
            SwiftOut swOutStored = context.GetTable<SwiftOut>().FirstOrDefault(o => o.QID == MyNewQid);

            XElement storedXdoc = swOutStored.Message;

            MessageBox.Show(storedXdoc.ToString());

            context.SwiftOuts.DeleteOnSubmit(swOutStored);
            context.SubmitChanges();
        }
    }
```

When I read the data from the new context, I get the xml with whitespaces removed.

Comment: What do you mean? What whitespace do you want to preserve? What does the XML string look like? XML itself doesn't preserve "whitespace". Even the `xml:space='preserve'` [doesn't preserve spaces](http://www.xmlplease.com/xml/xmlspace/)

Comment: Does `storedXdoc.ToString()` have the whitespace removed (i.e. before it was even written to the database)?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - xml contains element like this <elem> </elem> and when it's returned from database it's <elem/>.

Comment: @zdenok nothing wrong with that, and not related to whitespace in the first place. The two elemenst are identical. In fact, it's `XElement` that does this, not SQL Server or EF, precisely because they are identical

Comment: @mjwills storedXdoc is the data already received from database in separate context then it was written to database.

Comment: @zdenok what is your *actual* problem? Why do you want to display or write `<elem></elem>` instead of `<elem/>`? This sounds more like a misunderstanding or text formatting issue when you convert the XML data into strings

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos no it's done by DB, you can tell XElement to preserve whitespaces ant it works well untill you try to store such XElement in DB column of XML type. I know that they should be treated like identical XML but XSD schema has this field as not empty and when you remove the space then it's not going to validate. I don't have control over the source of the XML nor can I modify the XSD.

Comment: @zdenok this is not about whitespace! That's just an empty element. It does *not* contain whitespace, it's simply empty. Read the link in the very first comment.

Comment: @zdenok as for the database, you haven't provided the entity class, the context configuration or the table schema. Are you storing this into an `xml` field or `nvarchar(max)`? Are you forcing LINQ-to-SQL to serialize the XElement into a string? What you posted can't be used to reproduce, test or debug the problem

Comment: @zdenok and finally, your XML would be invalid even with the single space in it. The XSD *requires* that this element has a value and yet you are trying to ignore it by leaving it empty. Read the link that explains that `xml:space` `is only a signal of intent.` A validator or XSLT processor may very well ignore it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I've written in my comment to you that I'm storing into native xml data type column in MS SQL DB. I'm not originator of the xml I'm processing. It's originator thought that they will get around the problem of validity of the xml they generate, using schema that is ISO standard and they can not change it, by filling up element with space when in fact it should have no value (it's xml for old value vs new value where old value does not exist). It would pass through in validator if it would be <OldFld> </OldFld> but not if it's <OldFld/>.

Comment: @zdenok please update the *question* with all relevant information so people can reproduce the problem and try to find a solution. If I wanted to try this out right now I'd have to invent a lot of code and the table schema itself. As for ISO standard, first *which one*? Is it SWIFT? Which element? Does it really accept empty spaces as valid values? A lot of people have already worked with such protocols and can offer help a lot faster if you explain what you actually want.

Comment: @zdenok Second, XML is also a standard and it *doesn't* preserve whitespace the way you want to. Even so, your code only *loads* XML using `PreserveWhitespace`. There's no such attribute on the XElement itself, nor is it specified through a schema. SQL Server does support [XML Schemas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-schema-collections-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017). It could be that's what's needed?

Comment: @zdenok Third, if you don't specify the `xml:space="preserve"` directive neither XElement nor SQL Server know that you want to preserve whitespace. If you *do*,  SQL Server 2014 at least *does* preserve whitespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The XML datatype does **NOT** preserve your exact textual representation of the XML - it parses and tokenizes the XML for more optimal storage.

SQL Server does **not** guarantee that the XML returned is exactly the same (in terms of formatting, whitespaces etc.) as the input.

There's also no option or config setting to my knowledge to change this behavior.

See here for more details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/xml-data-type-and-columns-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

> Native storage as xml data type
>
> The data is stored in an internal representation that preserves the XML content of the data. .....
>   The InfoSet content **may not be** an identical copy of the text XML, because the following information **is not retained**: insignificant white spaces, order of attributes, namespace prefixes, and XML declaration.

*(emphasis was added by me)*

Comment: SQL Server will respect the `xml:space` attribute if it's there

Answer (score 1):

**Short version**

You need to add the `xml:space` attribute. `LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace` affects only how a string is parsed. It doesn't add the attribute. You should add :

```
serv.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve");
```

**Long version**

SQL Server does respect the `xml:space` attribute. This query :

```
create table #xmltest (field xml);

insert into #xmltest 
values
    ('<elem>         </elem>'),
    ('<elem xml:space="preserve">         </elem>');

select * from #xmltest;
```

Returns :

```
<elem />
<elem xml:space="preserve">         </elem>
```

The question's code doesn't specify that though. It *parses* a string into an XElement with the `PreserveWhitespace` but doesn't add that attribute. If the original string doesn't contain that attribute, XElement won't contain it either.

The code inserst the equivalent of the first value, which doesn'r require whitespace preservation.

For example :

```
XElement.Parse("<elem>   </elem>",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace).ToString();
```

Produces `<elem>   </elem>` which doesn't specify that whitespace should be preserved. `PreserveWhitespace` in this case *overrides* the default behaviour which is to ignore whitespace.

Without `PreserveWhitespace` Parse would ignore whitespace and return `<elem></elem>`.

On the other hand :

```
XElement.Parse("<elem xml:space='preserve'>   </elem>").ToString()
```

Produces `<elem xml:space="preserve">   </elem>`. There's no need to use the `PreserveWhitespace` flag, XElement itself recognizes and respects that flag.

If the source XML string contains whitespace but *doesn't* contain the `xml:space` attribute, it has to be added so other classes and applications like SQL Server know they have to preserve whitespace. The following code :

```
var serv=XElement.Parse("<elem>   </elem>",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
serv.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve");
serv.ToString();
```

Will return `<elem xml:space="preserve">   </elem>` which will be recognized by SQL Server.

**Bringing all this together**

This LINQ to SQL code :

```
var serv=XElement.Parse("<elem>       </elem>",LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
serv.SetAttributeValue(XNamespace.Xml + "space", "preserve");
Xmltests.InsertOnSubmit(new Xmltest{Field=serv});
```

Will insert :

```
<elem xml:space="preserve">       </elem>
```

Into the database

Comment: Thank you for proposed solution. I have only one problem with it, it is modifying original source xml and we wanted to avoid that. Anyway big thanks for your help.