# why is Xquery converting Vbcrlf to Vblf?

Tags: vb.net, xquery, xquery-sql

`<Root>
     <Row>
        <Col2>data</Col2>
        <Col3>data1</Col3>
        <Col4>data3</Col4>
        <Col1>Rowid1</Col1> 
     </Row> 
     <Row>
        <Col2>data</Col2>
        <Col3>data2</Col3>
        <Col4>data4</Col4>
        <Col1>Rowid2</Col1> 
     </Row>
</Root>`

The above xml is stored in sql server with datatype xml.
Here data3 is entered by user eg: data3 = A & vbnewline & B.

Query 1:

```
select column from table where [Sl_No]=7203
```

Result :  A & vbnewline & B

Query 2:

```
select column.value('(/Root/Row[Rowid=''1'']/col4/text())[1]','varchar(max)') from table where [Sl_No]=7203
```

Result :  A & vblf & B

All users use windows os.
why is xquery converting vbnewline(vbcrlf) to vblf?

Comment: I suspect that the CR was lost when it was stored in SQL Server: [Linq2SQL storing XElement to SQL Server database removes whitespaces](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52499464/1115360).

Comment: @AndrewMorton Query 2 giving result A & vblf & B for only some rowid for others it gives A & vbnewline & B. i.e. Cr is lost only for some rowids only.